# How to use variables in hyperlink using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, variables, hyperlink, header

I am using PHP and ASP.NET to pass variables over another page using a hyperlink.
Bit of the code:

```
<h3><?php echo $product["01"]["model"]; ?></h3>
    <div class="image_box">
         <img src="images/product/01.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
         <p><?php echo $product["01"]["brand"]; echo " "; echo $product["01"]["model"]; ?></p>
    </div></a>
```

So there is an image, the brand and the model displayed on the first page. When someone clicks that div, they are redirected to a new page called "product details" where they find all of the details of the product they've clicked on. This is done by ASP.NET (`<a href="productdetail.aspx?brand=Jori&model=IceCube>`).
So here, the brand and the model are passed to the next page where I can use that data.

But is there a way I can replace `<a href="productdetail.aspx?brand=Jori&model=IceCube>` by `<a href="productdetail.aspx?brand=$product["01"]["brand"]&model=$product["01"]["model"]>` for example? So I don't have to write the brand and model every time but just get them from where I've made them.

This is how I made the products, it is in PHP:

```
$product = array(     "01" => array("brand" => "JORI", "model" => "Shiva"),
                      "02" => array("brand" => "JORI", "model" => "Espalda"),
                      "03" => array("brand" => "JORI", "model" => "Indy"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My PHP is a little rusty but the following loop should do it for you.

```
<?php
    foreach($product as $p){
?>
<h3><?php echo $p["model"]; ?></h3>
<div class="image_box">
     <img src="images/product/<%php echo key($p); %>.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
     <p><a href="productdetail.aspx?brand=<?php echo $p["brand"]; ?>&model=<?php echo $p["model"]; ?>"><?php echo $p["brand"]; echo " "; echo $p["model"]; ?></a></p>
</div></a>
<?php
    }
?>
```